# Angular: Reinclude null values when filter parameter is empty

Tags: angularjs

I have a pretty simple `textbox` filtering an `ng-repeat` on some unordered `li`s. When I add a value to the `textbox` the items with the `null` values are removed and do not return even when the `textbox` is cleared. I have an idea of *why* this is happening (the search object now has an empty property which doesn't match the `nulls`), but I cannot figure out how to solve the problem. I've tried to `pop()` the property off of the search object with no luck.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.age" placeholder="Age"></input>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
            {{item.name}} - {{item.age}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function ListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {'name':'Carl', 'age':69},
    {'name':'Neil', 'age':54},
    {'name':'Richard'},
    {'name':'Chris', 'age':58}
  ];
}
```

Please checkout the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesseflorig/9Tpcw/) to better illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object). If I just add an `ng-change` to the textbox I can watch for an empty value and `delete` the property.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.age" ng-change="clear()" placeholder="Age"></input>
```

JS:

```
$scope.clear = function(){
    if($scope.search.age.length == 0){
        delete $scope.search.age;
    }
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesseflorig/9Tpcw/2/). I am aware the current `if` prevents a user from filtering on a single space, but so far this does not seem to cause a problem for me.

**BONUS:** `!` will return all `null` values and `!!` will return all not `null` values.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution I have found is writing a custom directive to modify the input field behaviour like this:

```
app.directive('deleteIfEmpty', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("ngModel", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (typeof scope.ngModel !== 'undefined' && scope.ngModel.length === 0) {
                    delete scope.ngModel;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And use it as follows:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="filter" delete-if-empty>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the input ng-model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchObj.age" placeholder="Age"></input>
```

Add this to your controller:

```
$scope.searchObj = {
}
```

And either of these will work in your html repeat:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchObj.age"
```

Or

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {age: searchObj.age || undefined}"
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdf67sbe/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use filter:search.  Looking at the Angular code, if your obj with an undefined age gets filtered (even when the input is empty) it will fall through this switch statement and always return false.  This switch doesn't get called the first time your ng-repeat is run because `$scope.search.age` is undefined.  After your first entry into the input and clearing it out, now `$scope.search.age` is an empty string...so the filter will always be run.

```
  switch (typeof obj) { ***<-- obj is undefined when you have a missing age***
    case "boolean":
    case "number":
    case "string":
      return comparator(obj, text);
    case "object":
      switch (typeof text) {
        case "object":
          return comparator(obj, text);
        default:
          for ( var objKey in obj) {
            if (objKey.charAt(0) !== '$' && search(obj[objKey], text)) {
              return true;
            }
          }
          break;
      }
      return false;
    case "array":
      for ( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (search(obj[i], text)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    default:
      return false;  ***<--falls through and just returns false***
  }
```

You can try writing your own filter function, something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/wuqu2/

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.age" placeholder="Age"></input>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:checkAge">
            {{item.name}} - {{item.age}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

  $scope.checkAge = function(item)
  {
      if($scope.search && $scope.search.age && $scope.search.age.length > 0)
      {
          return item.age && item.age.toString().indexOf($scope.search.age) > -1;
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will be trying this out shortly. However, is it possible to somehow `undefine` `$scope.search.age` so that it runs just like the initial load?

Comment: You can 'delete $scope.search.age' but I'm not sure how you would make that happen at the right time?

Comment: I just found out about `delete`! I posted an answer implementing that solution.